# Pivot table in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a pivot table from a view using dynamic columns but not sure how can I go about this - here is the table data sample -

```
question | userid | assessment_date| score
---------------------------------
Q1 1 2014-01-12 12:16:26.870 40
Q1 1 2014-01-14 12:28:38.943 40
Q1 1 2014-01-03 11:13:35.527 85
Q1 2 2014-01-09 11:16:19.450    20
Q1 2 2014-01-11 12:11:18.720    20
Q10 1 2014-01-14 12:28:38.943   70
Q10 1 2014-01-03 11:13:35.527   35
Q10 1 2014-01-11 12:11:18.720   35
Q10 2 2014-01-12 12:16:26.870   35
Q11 2 2014-01-11 12:11:18.720   28
Q11 2 2014-01-12 12:16:26.870   28
Q11 2 2014-01-14 12:28:38.943   28
Q12 2 2014-01-12 12:16:26.870   24
Q12 2 2014-01-11 12:11:18.720   64
```

Now I would like to display top ten questions with highest score result like this -

```
  question | 11-01-2014 | 12-01-2014 | 14-01-2014
  Q1 | 70 | 60 | 65
  Q3 | 85 |45 | 75
  Q7 |87 |54 | 63
```

I am sorry the code is not formatted well, hope it does make sense what I would like to achieve.

Sorry question is unique based on timestamp, and I missed one more column userid which links to the user table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There could be a problem here. What if the 3 highest scores are not exactly on the same date? This would make the column headings problematic.

Comment: "sorry the code is not formatted well", but you can edit and use the preview to format it some more. At any rate, it isn't actually *code*, and it would be good if you edit the question to show the code you have and be specific about the issue or error you're having.

Comment: hi stuart, I want to display first three date then top question scores for these three dates. Basically order by date desc and then question sore desc.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started, it is written in the general format for pivot tables but it is air code so you will likely need to change this.

```
SELECT question, '2014-01-11','2014-01-12','2014-01-14' 
FROM
(SELECT question, assessment_date, score FROM myTableName) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SELECT SUM(score) as SummedScore,
FOR assessment_date IN ('2014-01-11','2014-01-12','2014-01-14')
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Thanks craig, the date field is not fixed. it can be different dates for different user.

Comment: That's kind of how pivot tables work. You have to define the column names.